# AutoLayout correct positioning of button

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit

I have a view with a `UIButton` on it.  I've added two constraints:

Leading space to superview of 16
Top space to top layout of 265

Depending on which device I look, the button is in different locations.  The only way that I can get it consistent is to center it.  As a result, I've been building views off of a centered subview by setting vertical and horizontal distance.

I know that these constraints are actual number values and that the different iOS devices have different screen sizes.  How can I set it up so that the button will appear in the same location, relative to each device's screen size? For instance, if I have a button positioned a quarter of the way down the screen, how can I ensure that the button shows up a quarter of the way down the screen on all devices?

I feel like entire books could be written about how to set up screens with auto constraints.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to position the button?  Describe in plain English exactly how you'd want the button aligned.  And perhaps add screenshots of how it's showing up on the different devices, which is wrong, and why.

Comment: I have the button set up with the following constraints:

Leading space to superview equals 16
Top space to top layout = 265

This positions the button in different ways, depending on the device.  Ideally, I'd like the button to be positioned 1/4 of the way down the screen, regardless of the device upon which it is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution, without code, could be to :

Put the button in an UIView. Set the height of that view to be equal to the height of the controller's using an equal height constraint. Set the multiplier of that constraint at 3/4. Also add leading, trailing and a bottom constraints to the view. Now put your label in the view and pin it in the view with leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints. Done. If you're targeting iOS 9, use a LayoutGuide rather than UIView.

A more appropriate solution could be done with code : create an IBOutlet of the top constraint of your button in your controller. Change the constant of that IBOutlet in ViewDidLoad: method to self.view.frame.height / 4.

Comment: I don't see how the extra UIView is necessary.

Comment: It will not have a conflict between the bottom constraint and the height constraint ?

Comment: You have to set your constraints up correctly.  Scott's question isn't exactly clear on *exactly* how he wants his view set up or *exactly* what the problem is.  I left a comment to that effect.

Comment: He wants to have his button at the quarter of the controller view. It's pretty simple and pretty common. My solution has its constraints correctly set up. I don't get what you really mean by that. Actually, personally, I would prefer the second solution. But the first one works and does not deserve to be downvoted except if you propose a better solution without code.

Comment: His question *isn't* clear though.  You think he wants it a quarter of the way down.  He starts his question having commented about the button being a specific number of pixels from the top of the screen.  And he provides a for-instance.  The question simply isn't clear.  Your example using `self.view.frame.height / 4` probably doesn't work great with an iPad showing two apps in iOS 9, does it?

Comment: Picture-in-picture means app can be any size or (rectangular) shape.

Comment: So what could be your solution if I guess his problem right ? I'm interested